# Can't alter view in SQL Server 2017 with alter and create permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

When I try to run an alter view command like

```
alter view schema1.viewName as
select t1.col1, t2.col2 from schema2.table1 t1, schema2.table2 t2 
where {expression}
```

I get the error message

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed database role can perform this operation. Contact an administrator with sufficient permissions to perform this operation.

Even though I have alter permission on all things in `schema1`.

What's also strange if I change the query to say `create or alter view` instead of just `alter view`, then it runs fine.

Comment: *change or alter view* - are you definitely using MS SQL Server?

Comment: I bet you've got replication on.
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/error-trying-to-alter-procedure-on-replication-publisher

Comment: I do have replication on. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops. I meant create or alter view

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue with replication: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/error-trying-to-alter-procedure-on-replication-publisher